# How to compare sex ratio?

Tags: r, anova, chi-squared-test

How do you compare sex ratio in R?

I have surveyed a population of species and found 12 males and 1 female. I wish to compare the sex ratio in my sample to the expected 2:1 sex ratio of this species and then present the results of my analysis of this data. Then display my conclusions. I have had few lessons in R but am completely lost, any help with what tests or just what to would be a massive help and greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my answer to a similar problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595370/56940). Your case boils down to test $H_0:\theta=2/3$ and the data are $x=12$, $n=12+1$.

Comment: Please try to frame the title that articulates the query in question.

Comment: okay will do in future

Comment: thanks utobi, still bit confusing but think thats just me